# finding least date and unique content in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am getting data from the server in a file (**in format1**) everyday ,however i am getting the data for last one week.
I have to archive the data for 1.5 months exactly,because this data is being picked to make some graphical representation.
I have tried to merge the the files of 2 days and sort them uniquely (**code1**) ,however it didn't work because everyday name of raw file is changing.However Time-stamp is unique in this file,but I am not sure how to sort the unique data on base of a specific column also,is there any way to delete the data older than 1.5 months.
For Deletion ,The logic i thought is *deleting by fetching today's date - least date of that file* but again unable to fetch least date.

### Format1

```
r01/WAS2/oss_change0_5.log:2016-03-21T11:13:36.354+0000 | (307,868,305) | OSS_CHANGE | 

com.nokia.oss.configurator.rac.provisioningservices.util.Log.logAuditSuccessWithResources | RACPRS RNC 6.0 or 

newer_Direct_Activation:  LOCKING  SUCCEEDED audit[ | Source='Server' | User identity='vpaineni' | Operation 

identifier='CMNetworkMOWriterLocking' | Success code='T' | Cause code='N/A' | Identifier='SUCCESS' | Target element='PLMN-

PLMN/RNC-199/WBTS-720' | Client address='10.7.80.21' | Source session identifier='' | Target session identifier='' | 

Category code='' | Effect code='' | Network Transaction identifier='' | Source user identity='' | Target user identity='' | 

Timestamp='1458558816354']
```

### Code1

```
cat file1 file2 |sort -u > file3
```

### Data on Day2 ,the input file name Differ

```
r01/WAS2/oss_change0_11.log:2016-03-21T11:13:36.354+0000 | (307,868,305) | OSS_CHANGE | 

com.nokia.oss.configurator.rac.provisioningservices.util.Log.logAuditSuccessWithResources | RACPRS RNC 6.0 or 

newer_Direct_Activation:  LOCKING  SUCCEEDED audit[ | Source='Server' | User identity='vpaineni' | Operation 

identifier='CMNetworkMOWriterLocking' | Success code='T' | Cause code='N/A' | Identifier='SUCCESS' | Target element='PLMN-

PLMN/RNC-199/WBTS-720' | Client address='10.7.80.21' | Source session identifier='' | Target session identifier='' | 

Category code='' | Effect code='' | Network Transaction identifier='' | Source user identity='' | Target user identity='' | 

Timestamp='1458558816354']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written almost similar kind of code a week back.

Awk is a good Tool ,if you want to do any operation column wise.
Also , Sort Unique will not work as file name is changing
Both unique rows and least date can be find using awk.

1  To Get Unique file content

```
cat  file1  file2 |awk -F "\|" '!repeat[$21]++' > file3;
```

Here -F specifies your field separator
Repeat is taking 21st field that is time stamp
and will only print 1st occurrence of that time ,rest ignored
So,finally unique content of file1 and file2 will be available in file3

2  To Get least Date and find difference between 2 dates

```
Least_Date=`awk -F: '{print substr($2,1,10)}' RMCR10.log|sort|head -1`;
Today_Date=`date +%F` ;
Diff=`echo "( \`date -d $Today_Date +%s\` - \`date -d $Start_Date +%s\`) / (24*3600)" | bc -l`;
Diff1=${Diff/.*};
if [ "$Diff1" -ge "90" ]
then
```

Here we have used {:} as field separator, and finally substring to get exact date field then sorting and finding least

value.
Subtracting today's Date by using Binary calculator and then removing decimals.

Hope it helps .....

Comment: Good first answer. (But ;-) ) ... are you not familiar with the `$( ...cmd ...)` form of command-substitution? Join the 90s and you can code like `Diff=$(echo "( $( date -d .... )  / (24*3600)" | bc -l)` ;-) . (And strictly speaking this can be reduced to `Diff=$(( $( date -d ... ) / (24*3600) ))` (or similar) ). Also, use the `{}` tool in the format menu at the top left of the edit box to keep selected text as code/data/errorMsgs/Output formatted correctly. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks Shellter ,It's for the first time i replied on stackoverflow Post
and It's really good to see your response.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Sangeeta!!

Comment: Also will calculate the difference part using Shelter's way .Thanks Shelter!!